# Sum all elements of differently shaped numpy arrays stored in dictionary

Tags: python, numpy

I have a dictionary called `params`, containing weights with keys like "W1" and bias units for neural network. To calculate regularization for cost function i need to sum all weights and ignore biases. 
I've done this in following way:

```
layers_weights = filter(lambda str: str[0] == 'W', params)
layers_sums = map(lambda key: np.sum(params[key]),weights)
total_sum = np.array(list(layers_sums)).sum()
```

However i'm unexperienced in python and i wonder if there are more efficient and elegant ways to calculate this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to compute the denominator for your weight normalization? You can sum the weights more efficiently with:

```
total_sum = sum([np.sum(layer_w) for k, layer_w in params.items() if k.startswith('W')])
```

You can make this more expressive by using a *for* loop:

```
total_sum = 0
for k, layer_w in params.items():
   if k.startswith('W'):
       total_sum += np.sum(layer_w)
```

Comment: Thanks, I needed to compute L2 regularization. Your example would work great if change sum() to np.sum(), otherwise i get broadcast dimensions mismatch error

Comment: @mcstarioni Updated.